# how to make sure a record is always at the top in a given resultset in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a search query which yields a resultset based on input parameters and the result can be sorted (ASC/DESC) based on different parameters: price, duration etc (with pagination in place and limit of 10 records)

I now have a requirement wherein, if I have an `id` passed in, I'd like the corresponding record to be made to sticky at the top in the given resultset.

Lets say we have a package table like this:

```
Package
 - id
 - name
 - mPrice
 - vPrice
 - duration

// Searching pkg based on Price (in DESC order) where name = Thailand
sqlQuery = 
"SELECT p.id, p.name, p.mPrice, p.vPrice FROM package p 
WHERE p.name = LOWER('Thailand') 
ORDER BY (p.mPrice + p.vPrice) DESC 
LIMIT 10"
```

Let's assume the complete resultset is 20 records with ids 1 to 20. I'm now required to return record with id 14 to always be at the top. I came up with the following query, but this isn't working:

```
sqlQuery = 
"SELECT p.id, p.name, p.mPrice, p.vPrice FROM package p 
WHERE p.name = LOWER('Thailand') or p.id = 14
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN p.id=14 then 0 
else (p.mPrice + p.vPrice) 
end DESC 
LIMIT 10"
```

My guess as to why this is not working: After order by clause, the resultset is sorted in descending order, which is then truncated at 10 records. The record with id=14 may not be a part of this truncated set. Is this correct ?

How do I get record with id=14 to stick at the top ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
ORDER BY (p.id=14) DESC, (p.mPrice=p.vPrice) DESC
```

`p.id=14` returns `1` if the condition is true, `0` otherwise, so sorting descending brings the desired row to the top.

Returning a number from a comparison is a MySQL feature, with standard SQL you would write:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (p.id=14) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN (p.mPrice=p.vPrice) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

---

I find this easier to read than the `UNION`, and it might perform better.

Comment: Very cool! Should've thought of this. However, this did not work when I tried sorting it with ASC and I'm not sure why. `ORDER BY (p.id=14) ASC, (p.mPrice = p.vPrice) ASC`

Comment: `p.id=14` returns `1` if the condition is true, `0` otherwise. Sorting ascending puts the `0` first, so the one you want comes last...

Comment: Aha! Great. I'll just flip equality operator to id based on ASC/DESC . Do you have any ideas if this might perform better than UNION ?

Comment: Also, with your suggestion, I don't need to use the `OR` condition in my where clause, `WHERE p.name = LOWER('Thailand') or p.id = 14` => `WHERE p.name = LOWER('Thailand')`, correct ?

Comment: I would expect this to perform better than the `UNION`, but you should try this with your data. If you always want to show the record with `p.id=14` even if its `name` is not `thailand`, then the `OR` is required to make sure the record is in the list. If you only want it on top **if** it is `thailand`, then remove the `OR`. The `ORDER BY` clause can only sort the data returned by your query, it won't produce additional records.

Comment: I was about to use a union, but this looks so much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: While this question is about MySQL, I have added the general approach to my answer to make it more useful.

Answer (score 3):

Use a union to always have your package at top:

```
SELECT id, name, mPrice, vPrice FROM package WHERE id = 14
UNION
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.mPrice, p.vPrice FROM package p 
WHERE p.name = LOWER('Thailand') or p.id = 14
ORDER BY (p.mPrice = p.vPrice) DESC
LIMIT 9
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION` operation.

Comment: But you don't want to have the id 14 at top and once more in the "body"

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
order by 
 case when p.id=14 then then (select MAX(mPrice)+1 from package ) else
(p.mPrice = p.vPrice)  end desc
LIMIT 10
```

Instead of  **(select MAX(p.mPrice)+1 from package )**  you can give a constant value which would be always a maximun value, something like this

```
 order by 
 case when p.id=14 then then 1000000 else
(p.mPrice = p.vPrice)  end desc
LIMIT 10
```

which would be more effitient

Comment: Can you please explain what you are doing in that expression ?

Comment: @brainydexter: I am just getting the maximum value+1 for price , so that it will always be at the top