# how can i specify operator in order by clause?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following query (using jpa 2.0):

```
String query = "
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM package p
ORDER BY (p.id = :idPackage) DESC, (p.mPrice+p.vPrice) DESC 
LIMIT 10 ";

query.setParameter("idPackage", idPackage);
query.getResultList();
```

where package has the following attributes:

```
Package
 - id
 - name
 - mPrice
 - vPrice
 - duration
```

In the JPA query, when I try to execute it, it complains about the "=" operator in ORDER BY clause. Is there any way to get around it ??

This is the exception I get:

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node:`

Comment: why do you have that `=` there?

Comment: I learnt about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11823934/280924

Comment: Good you found it. About to point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use '=' in `order by` clause with JPA Queries. If you really need that, you can use `createNativeQuery` instead `createQuery`.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_orderby

Comment: Yes it does. There is no operator in that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `=` which is  a comparison operator:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM package p
ORDER BY (p.id = idPackage) DESC, (p.mPrice+p.vPrice) DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

EDIT: try:

```
String query = "
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM package p
ORDER BY (p.id = idPackage) DESC, (p.mPrice+p.vPrice) DESC 
LIMIT 10 ";
```

Comment: try to debug query by printing value of variable 'query'

Comment: Typo here and my bad! That is a compilation error and the code would not compile without the semicolon. I have the semicolon in my code.